# How can I restore a snapshot to an existing Aurora db instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I redeployed an Auraro cluster (postgresql 11). I did it by delete the existing one and re-create a new one. I have snapshot backup from the previous db instance and I'd like to restore the data to the existing instance.

I understand that Aurora doesn't support it. Is there a workaround for me to do that? Like whether I can download the snapshot to local in plain sql script format. Then manually restore them to the new instance?

Comment: why not restore de backup from the snapshots menu of RDS? Aurora allows to restore the snapshot but you create a new cluster. (you do that manually and delete and re-create is not the way)

Comment: You can [export snapshot data](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/announcing-amazon-relational-database-service-snapshot-export-to-s3/) to parquet format to S3. But I don't think that there is any "easy" way to import it to existing db.

Comment: I did it manually because the cluster need to be deployed with cloudformation stack. So I delete the old one and redeploy it with cloudformation.

Comment: You can create database from snapshot in cloudformation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that Aurora doesn't support it. Is there a workaround for
> me to do that? Like whether I can download the snapshot to local in
> plain sql script format. Then manually restore them to the new
> instance?

You can certainly accomplish that by doing the following:

1. Restore the snapshot to a new cluster (Cluster B).
2. Export the data from that cluster using `pgdump` or `mysqldump` depending on the Aurora database engine you are using. I suggest doing this in an EC2 instance in the same VPC.
3. Delete Cluster B.
4. Drop the database in your original cluster (Cluster A).
5. Load all the data from the export into Cluster A.

However, at that point all you have accomplished is that you will have maintained the RDS cluster's endpoint URL. If you design your system to allow changes to the RDS endpoint URL, then it would be much easier for you to simply restore the snapshot to the new cluster, swap the endpoint your application connects to, and delete the old cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method suggested by Teddy Aryono to restore the DB cluster.

Now rest is using DB host name, use secret manager to store your credentials so even if db host name is changing after restoring snapshot to new cluster you dont need to update application/lambda configurations.
(of-course you nee to update secret manager details with new host name after restore )

Answer (score -3):

You can restore from a DB cluster snapshot that you have saved. To restore a DB cluster from a DB cluster snapshot, use the AWS CLI command `restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot`.

In this example, you restore from a previously created DB cluster snapshot named `mydbclustersnapshot`. You restore to a new DB cluster named `mynewdbcluster`. You use Aurora PostgreSQL.

**Example:**

**For Linux, macOS, or Unix:**

```
aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot \
    --db-cluster-identifier mynewdbcluster \
    --snapshot-identifier mydbclustersnapshot \
    --engine aurora-postgresql
```

**For Windows:**

```
aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot ^
    --db-cluster-identifier mynewdbcluster ^
    --snapshot-identifier mydbclustersnapshot ^
    --engine aurora-postgresql
```

Furthermore, you can also do it using AWS Management Console, or RDS API. Read [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html) for details.

Comment: It is to restore to a new cluster, I'd like to restore to an existing cluster.